# PHP dynamic var from string

Tags: php, dynamic, var

I know how PHP dynamic vars work, I know I can access object property like
`$object->{'somethingWith$var'};` or like `$object->$var;`

But what I try to accomplish is to access `$object->property->subproperty` from `$object` and the string `$string = 'property->subproperty';`.

I tryed `$object->$string`, `$object->{$string}`, `$object->$$string` hahaha, none worked.

Does anybody know how to do this ? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write simple function, something like this:

```
function accessSubproperty($object, $accessString) {
    $parts = explode('->', $accessString);
    $tmp = $object;
    while(count($parts)) {
        $tmp = $tmp->{array_shift($parts)};
    }
    return $tmp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I think is the best then.
I will rather use the foreach approach suggested by nl-x bellow for I will use it only once, but the idea is here and you were first.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this like that.

You have to first assign `$property = $object->$propertyName` and then access var you wanted to `$property->$subpropertyName`.

In your examples string `property->subproperty` will be treated like variable name which obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation and fast answer, I was looking for a solution though.
also, I usually can access directly $object->property->subproperty without assignment, or I didn't get what you meant :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because all you are accomplishing with your tries is getting `$object{'property->subproperty'}` which off course is not the same as `$object->{'property'}->{'subproperty'}`.

What you can do is:

```
$ret = $object;
foreach (explode("->",$string) as $bit)
    $ret = $ret->$bit;
```

Or you will have to go to the ugly and evil [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval) (let the downvoting start):

```
eval("return \$object->$string;")
```

Comment: The only things this adds to [Brabec's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28454989/227299) is the fact that  you could use `eval` which is really not a great suggestion because of the security implications.

Comment: I appreciate the foreach way, and will use it.
I don't rely on eval 0:)
Thanks

Comment: @disadb So you used the answer, but accepted the other answer :) ?